# Jinja template comparison operators not working

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to use
{% if item.quantity < 10 %}

this is not working, <=, >, >= these opertors are also not working only == opertor is working

I found no reason in the internet for this to not work.

If someone knows how to solve this, your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax looks OK.  But you may be comparing a string to a number.  Try casting item.quantity to an int with the "|int" filter and then do the compare.  For example in the following line of code that is what is happening:

```
{% if person.grade|int <= 25 %}
```

You can check out Jinja's built in filters (and particularly the int one) at:

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-filters

Comment: I have tried |int |float both didn't work

Comment: You probably need to show people a bit more code then. . . .most likely the error isn't in the snippet you are showing in your post.  Also make sure to check what item.quantity is outputting in the template.  You know, like so:  <div>debug: {{item.quantity}}</div>